# ASP.NET how to remove SameSite cookie parameter

Tags: ios, asp.net, cookies, samesite

I have added

```
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" cookieSameSite="None" timeout="5" />
```

to my web.config file. But the application is still not working on iOS 12. Is there a way to remove SameSite cookie parameter in ASP.NET if device running iOS 12?

Answer (score 0):

Found below:

> Source

- https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients

> Versions of Safari and embedded browsers on MacOS 10.14 and all
>   browsers on iOS 12. These versions will erroneously treat cookies
>   marked with `SameSite=None` as if they were marked `SameSite=Strict`.
>   This bug has been fixed on newer versions of iOS and MacOS.

Bug Report is here - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181